# chrome browser on Android

Tags: google-chrome, browser, resolution

i just bought the new nexus 5 which screen is on full hd.
My surprise was not so good when I opened chrome and I saw that the browser was not showing websites in full hd but in a ridiculous 1024 resolution. Searching on the parameters and on the web I didn't find a way to change the resolution to 1080.

Can't you tell me a way to get a full hd phone browser ?
Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are referencing.  The browser does not "downsample" the content.  I have a Nexus 5 myself and have no issues with the Chrome browser

Comment: It is not the visual resolution that I mean but the displayed pixels from a website. My website has a specific width wider that 1024. You can see yourself www.DAMAaaS.com